# How to get all the words in a webpage - Python3

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping

Suppose that we have this link: [CBC Site Map](http://www.cbc.ca/sitemap/)

and I want to get all the words on this page such as Arts, books, etc.
How can I do that with Python3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the words from the URL?

```
import requests
with requests.Session() as c:
    page = c.get('http://www.cbc.ca/sitemap/')
    print (page.content)
```

Or, maybe this is what you want.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

resp = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.cbc.ca/sitemap/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, from_encoding=resp.info().get_param('charset'))

for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    print(link['href'])
```